# CSS - Columns with equal height, set width and vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create 2 columns of equal *height* but with set % *widths*.

One of the columns will have text that should be vertically aligned. I tried using `display: table-cell` but could then couldn't set the *width* correctly.

This image shows what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share your HTML structure?

Comment: why couldn't you set the width correctly with table-cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.box img {
  flex: 0.6;
}

.box .text {
  flex: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" />
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi quis hic suscipit recusandae ad veritatis dolorem expedita placeat rerum architecto provident ipsa, consequuntur, assumenda vitae explicabo sapiente laboriosam cum cupiditate.</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

For better browser support, you can use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
}
.sixty {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: gray;
}
.forty {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner sixty">
    this is an image<br>
    width = 60%
  </div>
  <div class="inner forty">
    this is some text<br>
    width = 40%<br>
    text = vertically alligned
  </div>
</div>
```